# Reachart minPointSize props does not work when using in stackedBarChart

Tags: recharts, stacked-bar-chart

Problem: I am working on stackedBarChart where on particular data if there is no data we need show dash as a indication there but there is data normal we have to show stackedBar
but when trying to show dash using minpointsize prop of stackedbarchart it does not work properly , it shows up even when there is data.

Comment: Unfortunately this prop is not supported in stacked bar chart: this is what their docs says: "In stacked bar charts, minPointSize might not be respected for tightly packed values. So we strongly recommend not using this props in stacked BarChart."